# Singular and plural nouns

Tags: grammar, singular-vs-plural

> I like taking **naps** in the afternoon.
> I like taking **a nap** in the afternoon.

Which one is grammatically correct when talking about it in general?

In an English workbook there are several substitution drills of this kind.

In the pattern the singular form of the noun is used, but in the substitution sets the plural form is used:

> They like cycling, but they don't like taking a nap.
>
> - She/take naps
>   read comic books

Which one is the answer here?

She likes taking naps, but she doesn't like reading comic books.
Or
She likes taking a nap, but she doesn't like reading a comic book.

Answer (score 1):

Both are acceptable, but when selecting one you'd do well to be guided by the principle of [parallelism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parallelism_(grammar)).

> They like *cycling*, but they don't like *napping*.

> She *takes naps* and *reads comic books*.

> In the afternoon, he *has a drink* and *takes a nap*.